# Could not find Digikam

Tags: linux, installation, git, kde, make

I have compiled and made the Digikam source code from GIT. Everything went right. At last, I typed 'sudo make install' and it went successful. But after this, I don't know where the digikam is installed. It is not shown in Application Launcher as other applications/softwares are shown.

Answer (score 0):

look at the `Makefile`, the install paths are defined there.

Comment: I am unable to figure out the install path. There are lots of paths for different libraries.

Comment: maybe try harder. i can and will not guess the path for you and i am certain it is somewhere in that Makefile

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the one of the following commands from a terminal

`which digikam` or `whereis digikam`

the first one should show you the full path of the program; the second also lists all the directories where are stored program configuration files, man pages, and so on.

You might want to look [here](http://ss64.com/bash/which.html) and [here](http://ss64.com/bash/whereis.html) for more info.